# how to manage microservices with meteor

Tags: meteor, microservices

I try to build a poc to play with microservices and meteorjs.
I did 2 services:
- the first one is a simple CRUD to manage contacts
- the second manage products and orders

I've learn i can join microservices with `DDP.connect('http://server1.com/);`but i try to understand how to understand how and where to unify things.
The aim is a simple app for example where a connected user can add some products in a basket. Then, where do i create the layout and everything which call the webservices to connect and to add to the basket ?
Another point, if my microservices have options (ie send email when order if confirmed), is there a way to have a simple option page where i can find all options from all services available ?

For example:
--- My beautiful admin page ---

> == Service One ==
>   x - option 1
>   - option 2
>   x - option 3
>
> == Service two ==
>        - option 1
>   x - option 2
>
> [save]

Comment: this might be useful for you: https://bulletproofmeteor.com/architecture/microservices-with-meteor-and-ddp

Comment: I've saw this resources but 90$ ...